# Unhandled exception at 0x00B67361

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to read .dat files into 2D array, I tried successfully read same files into 1D arrays such that each line for each array. However, with the code below for 2D array a message box pop up stating " Unhandled exception at 0x00B67361 in ConsoleApplication11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." and does not finish the execution". What's the reason behind the unhandled exception? I use VS 2012 express edition.

```
do {
        char * s = find_data.cFileName;

        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(s); // open a file
        if (!fin.good()) 
            return 1; // exit if file not found

        // read each line of the file
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            // read an entire line into memory
            char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
            int n = 0;
            int s = 0;
            int m = 0;

            // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
            const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE][MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
            for (m = 1; m < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; m++)
            {
                fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

                // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
                // a for-loop index
                //char* next_token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
                char *next_token;
                // parse the line
                token[0][0] = strtok_s(buf, DELIMITER, &next_token); // first token
                //token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
                if (token[0][0]) // zero if line is blank
                {
                    for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
                    {
                        token[m][n] = strtok_s(0, DELIMITER, &next_token); // subsequent tokens
                        //token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
                        if (!token[m][n]) break; // no more tokens
                    }
                }
            }
            // process (print) the tokens
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    cout << "Token[" << i << "," << j << "] = " << token[i][j] << endl;
                    cout << endl;

                }
        }
        // Your code here
    } while( FindNextFile( h, & find_data ) );
    FindClose( h );
```

Comment: This title is not going to be useful to others with the same problem. They are unlikely to have an exception at 0x00B67361, and even if they did, the reason is probably different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.  What's the reason behind the unhandled exception?

A: You're reference a null pointer in your code :)

SUGGESTION:

Single-step through the MSVS debugger.  Pay careful attention every time strtok_s() returns "0" ... and make sure you don't try to access that null pointer later.  Make sure you're actually processing 8-bit characters (who knows: your compiler settings might be giving you 16-bit Unicode).  Most important: identify the exact line that's causing the crash, and work backward from the data that line is processing.

MSVS has a great debugger: you should be able to find - and correct - the problem in no time :)

Good luck!

Comment: I found the problem starts from {char *s = find_data.cFileName;}  line. the debuggers say: unable to read memory. and I'm using Multi-byte character set. does that has anything to do with this?

Comment: Yes.  It says that find_data == 0.

Comment: Still can't find out why find_data == 0 , I've run almost same code and nothing like this happened. The prior part to this code is {uint64_t a = GetTimeMs64();
 cout << a << endl;
 HANDLE h;
 WIN32_FIND_DATA find_data;
 h = FindFirstFile( "*.dat", &find_data );
 if( h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
  cout<<"error"<<endl;

 }}
why it does not print "error" if the handle value is wrong